# Fluentd config to collect logs for each namespace separately

Tags: kubernetes, logging, namespaces, fluentd

What would be the Fluentd configuration to collect logs and create a separate log file / folder path of each namespace separately ?

I want to use a Fluentd instance and have a configuration that would help me segregate and group logs of each namespace separately, and then zip them separately to be sent over http.

Answer (score 0):

One starting with (kubernetes.var.log...) should contain the namespace, and therefore you can filter based on specific namespaces and decide how to handle those specific logs.
If, for any reason, the log path in your cluster does not contain the namespace in its path, you can also use the [kubernetes](https://github.com/fabric8io/fluent-plugin-kubernetes) plugin.

It will enrich your logs with metadata relevant to the cluster, and allow you to extract the namespace logs originated from and deal with them accordingly.

Refer to this for [collecting logs with Fluentd](https://isitobservable.io/observability/kubernetes/how-to-collect-logs-with-fluentd) ,[Blog](https://blog.opstree.com/2019/12/17/collect-logs-with-fluentd-in-k8s-part-2/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand the concept how to go about it. I was hoping for a sample configuration directly that i can use or work on top of it :)